# Initialization of ORACLE database In unit tests

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, docker-compose, junit4, spring-boot-test

I have been trying to write some unit tests for my application. I am using oracle database in a docker container.

I am using `ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript()` to initialize the database from sql files. This work if I am using MySql database but I have PL/SQL in my Oracle schema and I get an exception when schemas executed (I am 100% sure that schemas work).

```
END; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

I guess `ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript()` does not support PL/SQL.

As I don't want to do volume binding in my docker-compose.yml I can't initialize tables when I start the docker container.

1. Is there a better way of initializing tables for my JUnit tests that will work for any database technology?
2. As you can see, I am generating tables before tests and dropping them after but I have other tests that will use those tables so I want to create tables once for all of the tests related to oracle. Is there any way of doing that?

```
@SpringBootTest
public class JdbcUserDaoImplTest {

    private static JdbcUserDaoImpl userDao;

    private User user;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws SQLException {
        userDao = new MysqlJdbcUserDaoImpl(dataSource());
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(Objects.requireNonNull(userDao.getDataSource()).getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("pre.schema.sql"));
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(userDao.getDataSource().getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("schema.sql"));
    }

    ... TEST CASES ...

    public static DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1507:XE");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("system");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("oracle");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void destroy() throws SQLException {
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(Objects.requireNonNull(userDao.getDataSource()).getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("drop.sql"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Example of undeployable SQL

```
CREATE TRIGGER item_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON items
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF :NEW.item_date IS NULL
    THEN
        SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO :NEW.item_date FROM DUAL;
    END IF;

    IF :NEW.item_uid IS NULL
    THEN
        SELECT SYS_GUID() INTO :NEW.item_uid FROM DUAL;
    END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Show us the undeployable PLSQL, please.

Comment: I updated the question @peter.hrasko.sk

Comment: Although the trigger is (DB-wise) pretty badly written, it's valid PL/SQL in terms of syntax. I googled a bit and found only references to `ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript()` indeed not working with PL/SQL stored programs. Have a look at this workaround perhaps: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19999

Comment: Btw. which version of Oracle DB you use? As I see it, you may even remove the trigger and use other means of autofilling the two columns.

Comment: I use oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g docker container. There are multiple places that I use these kind of syntax so I prefer not changing the SQL if possible.

Comment: OK, I see. With Oracle 11 you are out of luck with the mentioned _other means of autofilling_. Alas, I cannot help you further.